Setting a wavy sidebar with `tcolorbox`
The code given in this answer and copied below works with mdframed.
How to do the same with tcolorbox?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newcommand\wavydecor{%
    \draw[decoration={coil,aspect=0.1,segment length=5pt,amplitude=0.8pt},decorate,line width=1.5pt,black]
      (O|-P) -- (O);
}

\newmdenv[
hidealllines=true,
innerleftmargin=10pt,
innerrightmargin=0pt,
innertopmargin=0pt,
innerbottommargin=0pt,
leftmargin=-10pt,
skipabove=.5\baselineskip,
skipbelow=.5\baselineskip,
singleextra={\wavydecor},
firstextra={\wavydecor},
secondextra={\wavydecor},
middleextra={\wavydecor}
]{wavysbar}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{wavysbar}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}


In tcolorbox you could say
borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{snake, rounded corners}
by using \usetikzlibrary{snakes}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}% 1/3
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}% 2/3

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox{twavysbar}{
boxrule=0pt, frame hidden,
notitle, boxsep=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, 
colback=white,
enhanced,
borderline west={1.5pt}{0pt}{snake, rounded corners},% 3/3
}

\lipsum[2]
\begin{twavysbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{twavysbar}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}

